# Mathematical Induction Proof, need help on how to explain this one statement.

Tags: abstract-algebra, induction

Use Mathematical Induction to prove that for [; n>=1 ;], that $ b_n=(1/2)((3^n)+1) $

Solution:

Basic case: 
For [; n = 1 ;]
   $$ b_1 = 2 = 1/2((3^1)+1) $$

Assume that for some k  $$ b_k = 1/2(3^k + 1) $$

Then  $$ b_{k+1} = 3b_k - 1 $$
                       $$ =  3(1/2)(3^k + 1) - 1 $$
                       $$ =  3/2(3^k) + 3/2 - 1 $$
                       $$ =  3/2(3^k) + 1/2 $$
                       $$ =  1/2(3^{k+1} + 1 $$

I just want to figure out how exactly we got $ b_{k+1} = 3b_k - 1 $ in the first place? What has led us to that assumption or where did it come from (I understand everything else)?

Comment: How are the $b_n's$ defined?

Answer (score 1):

In the problem statement, there should be $b_1=2$ and $b_{n+1}=3b_n-1$. Without those, you don't have enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: Well we solved for $ b_1 = 2 $, are you saying there is no possible way to reach $ b_{k+1} = 3b_k - 1 $ unless it was given to you?

Comment: You need some input information.  In your question, there is nothing at all to tell us what $b_n$ is, just a formula we are supposed to prove. It looks like there is supposed to be something more inside the square brackets.